# Use next() function within class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that predicts the weather using probabilities from a matrix. The matrix is small:

```
weather = [
    [0.4,  0.3,  0.1,  0.05, 0.1,  0.05],
    [0.3,  0.4,  0.1,  0.1,  0.08, 0.02],
    [0.2,  0.3,  0.35, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
    [0.1,  0.2,  0.25, 0.3,  0.1,  0.05],
    [0.15, 0.2,  0.1,  0.15, 0.3 , 0.1 ],
    [0.1 , 0.2,  0.35, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.2 ]
]
```

Each row corresponds to one type of weather (in the order given above) and each column is the probability of one type of weather occurring the following day (also in the order given above). I have a written a class that computes the probability that for example, the weather will hail, given that it was sunny the day before. I made this into an iterator as shown below:

```
class Markov:
    def __init__(self):
        #Initialize Markov object
        self.weather = {'sunny':0, 'cloudy':1, 'rainy':2, 
                        'snowy':3, 'windy':4, 'hailing':5}
        self.dat = np.array([])
        self.previous_day = None
        self.following_day = None

    #load data
    def load_data(self, array):
        # implement here
        self.dat = array

    # Get probability of weather on following day given weather on #previous day
    def get_prob(self, previous_day, following_day):

        self.previous_day = previous_day
        self.following_day = following_day
        return self.dat[self.weather[previous_day]][self.weather[following_day]]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    #function I would like to write. 
    def get_weather_for_day(self, day):
        pass

    #Implement the next function which does most of the heavy lifting. 
    def __next__(self):
        outcome = ''.join(np.random.choice(a = list(self.weather.keys()), size = 1, p=self.dat[self.weather[self.following_day]]))
        self.following_day = self.previous_day
        return "The next day's weather is " + outcome

#Run the code
weather_today = Markov()
weather_today.load_data(weather)
print(weather_today.get_prob('sunny', 'hailing'))
next(weather_today)

#Output
"The next day's weather is rainy"

>next(weather_today)
"The next day's weather is windy"
>next(weather_today)
>"The next day's weather is sunny"
```

This is good but laborious for the user. What about if I wanted to return the weather on say, day 10? Any ideas as to how I can implement that? The method I would like is get_weather_for_day(self, day), where `day` specifies the number of days.

My assumption is that I would use `__next__` function within `get_weather_for_day(self, day)` but I am not sure how to implement this?

In short what I want is the following output:

```
weather_today = Markov()
weather_today.load_data(weather)
weather_today.get_weather_for_day(5)

#output
In 5 days, the weather will be snowy
```

Comment: Why not use an array index?

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

When your instance is used as an iterator (which it will be in a `for` loop, since you just return `self` in `__iter__`). the method `__next__` is called for each `for` iteration.

So, you can use your instance straight-out in a for loop, and control the number of iterations  by having an index, which can be provided by `enumerate`. Besides that, you might want to zero-out the some states before iterating - if so, do that inside `__iter__` before returning `self`:

```
class Markov:
    ...
    get_weather_for_day(self, day):
         for daycount, prediction in enumerate(self):
             if daycount == day:
                  return prediction
```

You just would need to take care if you want to (1) preserve the "previous_day" state before calling this method, or (2) using this code in a multi-threaded or asynchronous program, (such as the backend for a web application where this is used in a view).

In those cases, you might create a copy of the instance in its current state inside the function, before proceeding with the iteration

```
 from copy import copy

 class Markov:
    ...

    def __next__(self):
        outcome = ''.join(np.random.choice(a = list(self.weather.keys()), size = 1, p=self.dat[self.weather[self.following_day]]))
        self.following_day = self.previous_day
        return  outcome

    def __iter__(self):
         return copy(self)
    ...
    get_weather_for_day(self, day):

         for daycount, prediction in enumerate(iter(self)):
             if daycount == day:
                  return f"In {day} days the weather will be {prediction}!"
```

(Ah, of course you have to change the return value of `__next__` by itself, so that you can format the output as you asked in this function -)